# Multiple tables Offline Sync Xamarin.Forms & Azure

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin

I want to enable Offline sync between a Xamarin.Forms mobile app & Azure. I've successfully run the ToDoAzure with Offline Sync app, however have one query when scaling up to my own app.

There is a section of code in the sample app:

```
public bool IsOfflineEnabled
{
    get { return todoTable is Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.IMobileServiceSyncTable<TodoItem>; }
}
```

How would I scale that up to manage multiple tables? I've got 3 tables I want to sync & have offline access to. Do I just add multiple parameters in the get? or do I need to declare offline sync enabled for each table and have a boolean value for each?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 3 tables, that is critical. That part of the code that you present seems a bit redundant and definitely not critical in enabling syncing (sync would work even without it just you may use it for whatever other reason in your code).